# Producing full list of Fibonacci numbers which fit in an Int

Tags: scala, fibonacci-sequence

I am progressing through the problems listed at projecteuler.com as I learn Scala ([my blog where I am covering this experience](http://fromjavatoscala.blogspot.com)). I have written a function to produce all the Fibonacci numbers possible in an `Int` (it's only 47). However, the resulting function feels imperative (not functional).

```
  val fibsAll = {
    //generate all 47 for an Int
    var fibs = 0 :: List()
    var current = fibs.head
    var next = 1
    var continue = true
    while (continue) {
      current = fibs.head
      fibs = next :: fibs
      continue = ((0.0 + next + current) <= Int.MaxValue)
      if (continue)
        next = next + current
    }
    fibs.reverse
  }
```

I am looking for feedback on this code:

1. To what degree does the presence of even a single `var` (there are four here) indicate an erred approach from a functional standpoint?
2. Given I want to return a `List[Int]`, what better way is there to do this recursively as opposed to my current (odd) "while loop" approach?

I am finding the transition from imperative to functional thinking quite challenging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
object Euler002 extends App{
  // Infinite List (Stream) of Fibonacci numbers 
  def fib(a: Int = 0, b: Int = 1): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(a, fib(b, a+b)) 

  // Take how many numbers you want into a List 
  val fibsAll = fib() takeWhile {_>=0} toList
  fibsAll reverse 
}
```

Take a look at [this](http://sites.google.com/a/ifrn.edu.br/leonardo/disciplinas/2011-1/plp/projeto-euler#TOC-Problema-2).

Comment: Tyvm for your answer. I had already found the "sum the series" answers. However, that solution doesn't work as I'm doing a modified version of the problems. So, I need the above function signature as-is; no parameters and returning all 47 values as a List[Int] in ascending order.

Comment: I modified the code to convert the stream into a list

Comment: LOL! Okay. That works. It still misses the point, though. I can't assume there are  47 values in the function (although I can in the test case validating the results)..

Comment: Use `takeWhile {_>0}` to get all numbers below `Int.MaxValue`

Comment: I will say I am immediately excited (and confused and dismayed) by the prospect of what you are implying. So, when two Int-s are added and the result is larger than Int.MaxValue, instead of generating a ValueOutOfRangeException, it returns the result rolling over the range (it basically forms a ring where 2147483647 is followed by -2147483648). That's why takeWhile works. I had assumed that I would get an exception and had to catch the terminating condition PRIOR to the range rollover. BTW, I need my sequence to include the (0, 1) start and not the projecteuler.com incorrect start of (1, 2).

Comment: I prefer to use BigInt instead of Int. BigInt has no upper limit.

You could redefine `fibs` replacing `Int` with `BigInt`. `fibsAll` would look like:   `val fibsAll = fib() takeWhile {_<Int.MaxValue} toList`

Answer (score 6):

What you should seek in functional programming is [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29). That means you can replace something with its value, and the surrounding code will still work.

For example:

```
var continue = true
while (continue) {
```

So, `continue` is `true` (at least the first time this is executed). Can I replace, then, `while (continue)` with `while (true)` and have the rest of the code work as expected? The answer is no, of course.

However, consider that this code generates a `fibsAll` which is a list of fibonacci numbers less than `Int.MaxInt`. If I replace the whole definition of `fibsAll` with that list, will the rest of the code act as expected? Yes, it will!

So even though you lost referential transparency in the small, you still kept it in the large. If you need to compromise on FP, this is the kind of compromise you should seek.

Having said that, there are many ways of getting around this. A `while` loop is often easily converted into recursion -- and, if tail recursive, recursion is as fast as, and sometimes faster than, `while` loops. For example:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec // turns non-tail recursion into an error
val fibsAll = {
    @tailrec def recurse(current: Int, next: Int, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] =
        if (next >= current) recurse(next, next + current, current :: acc)
        else acc
    recurse(0, 1, Nil).reverse
}
```

A non-tail recursive version of it is simpler, and since the list is pretty small, you are unlikely to get stack overflow errors.

```
val fibsAll = {
    def recurse(current: Int, next: Int): List[Int] =
        if (next >= current) current :: recurse(next, next + current)
        else Nil
    recurse(0, 1)
}
```

Another way of thinking of it is with `iterate`, which produces an element based on the previous one. For `Iterator` (not really a functional class) and `Stream`, it can be infinite. With other collections, such as `List`, you can define a number of elements. This solution uses a `Stream`, and then limit it as appropriate:

```
val fibsAll = (
    Stream.iterate(0 -> 1){ case (a, b) => (b, a + b) }
    takeWhile { case (a, b) => b >= a }
    map { case (a, b) => a }
    toList
)
```

There's also `unfold`, which you can find on blogs and on the [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) library. It combines `map`, `iterate` and `takeWhile` in a single function:

```
val fibsAll = (0, 1).unfold[List, Int]{ 
    case (a, b) => 
        if (a > b) None 
        else Some(a -> (b, a + b))
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! That was the principle I was trying to learn, but didn't know how to ask; referential transparency! And thank you for your being so detailed in your comments. It really helped me see what you are saying concretely. And to see that if/when a compromise is needed (say for performance reasons), encapsulating the referential transparency loss within a method is the best pathway for quality software engineering. Again, tysvm for your answer.